# why does compressing deparse(substitute()) into a function seem to behave inconsistently?

Tags: r

I apologize that I am only modestly familiar with formatting conventions but I hope this is nevertheless readable.

To save myself typing (and errors) I wrote

```
depSub<-function(object) deparse(substitute(object)) # return name of object as string
```

This seems to works as expected

depSub(qq)

[1] "qq"

> deparse(substitute(qq))

[1] "qq"

> 

But inside a function the result is different

```
foo<-function(object){
  name1<-depSub(object)
    name2<-deparse(substitute(object))
    print(c("name1=",name1,"name2=",name2))
}
```

foo(qq)

[1] "name1=" "object" "name2=" "qq"

Any illumination of why this happens would be much appreciated

Comment: What's going on it that `depSub` returns the name of the variable you pass to it. When you call `depSub(object)`, you are passing a variable named "object". It doesn't know it has to go up the stack. What if you defined `bar<-function(obj) foo(obj)` and you called it with `bar(apple)`. What should `depSub` return when called inside `foo`? It could reasonably return `object`, `obj` or `apple`. You need to be clear how you want to define the function. Often if you want a name it's more extensible to allow changing it as a parameter `foo<-function(x, name=deparse(substitute(x))) {}`

Answer (score 0):

We could change the `deparse` to `quote` and then `eval`uate  it  inside `foo`

```
depSub<-function(object) quote(substitute(object))
foo<-function(object){
   name1 <- deparse(eval(depSub(object)))
    name2 <- deparse(substitute(object))
   print(c("name1=",name1,"name2=",name2))
}



foo(qq)
#[1] "name1=" "qq"     "name2=" "qq"
```